# Extjs Combobox setValue() and SetRawValue() method difference?

Tags: extjs

Extjs Combobox setValue() and SetRawValue() method difference ?

1) Can we set valueField and displayField using both method.
2) Both method handle same events.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation you can easily understand the difference:

> [`setRawValue`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-method-setRawValue) Sets the field's raw value directly, **bypassing** value conversion,
>   change detection, and validation. **To set the value with these
>   additional inspections see [`setValue`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-method-setValue)**.

Comment: Thanks. understand actual difference.